# Is it possible to get all console logs with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get data from an Evolution BlackJack, I realized that the information needs to be fully displayed in the DevTool Console (Pictures at the end of the post).

I tried with

`driver.get_log('performance')`

return this:

```
[{'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.webSocketFrameReceived","params":{"requestId":"15920.856","response":{"mask":false,"opcode":1,"payloadData":"{\\"id\\":\\"aef4586d-a054-4624-8944-9e94eec2b3fa\\",\\"type\\":\\"next\\",\\"payload\\":{\\"data\\":{\\"highrollerHouseBets\\":{\\"id\\":\\"f6d1ad06-dd6b-4995-9cb2-63311aa4141f\\",\\"iid\\":\\"house:162398917195\\",\\"game\\":{\\"name\\":\\"Scarab Spin\\",\\"icon\\":\\"stake-game-slots-scarab\\"},\\"bet\\":{\\"__typename\\":\\"CasinoBet\\",\\"id\\":\\"f6d1ad06-dd6b-4995-9cb2-63311aa4141f\\",\\"active\\":false,\\"payoutMultiplier\\":13.1,\\"amountMultiplier\\":1,\\"amount\\":0.0575,\\"payout\\":0.7532499999999999,\\"updatedAt\\":\\"Tue, 13 Jun 2023 02:31:42 GMT\\",\\"currency\\":\\"eth\\",\\"user\\":null}}}}}"},"timestamp":767861.646359}},"webview":"98FB9B06E1146D614A3E617E102ED2D8"}',
  'timestamp': 1686623503779},
 {'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.webSocketFrameSent","params":{"requestId":"15920.856","response":{"mask":true,"opcode":1,"payloadData":"{\\"type\\":\\"ping\\"}"},"timestamp":767861.717861}},"webview":"98FB9B06E1146D614A3E617E102ED2D8"}',
  'timestamp': 1686623503849},
 {'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.webSocketFrameReceived","params":{"requestId":"15920.856","response":{"mask":false,"opcode":1,"payloadData":"{\\"type\\":\\"pong\\"}"},"timestamp":767861.944991}},"webview":"98FB9B06E1146D614A3E617E102ED2D8"}',
  'timestamp': 1686623504076}]
```

and

`driver.get_log('browser')`

return this

```
[{'level': 'SEVERE',
  'message': "https://js.intercomcdn.com/vendor-modern.a1c39d6c.js 1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://nexus-websocket-a.intercom.io/pubsub/5-Huu70_r42HzjAF5Qt0c-b5aEN_tWmQAJpdTtHgBspH3xoAToVj6-MKfoaD-qETxdQhLFD0d_65yIBSWMGX8VpTAJrw-5VsVPluD3?X-Nexus-New-Client=true&X-Nexus-Version=0.10.0&user_role=undefined' failed: ",
  'source': 'network',
  'timestamp': 1686623607459}]
```

but both don't return the result I want (image included at the bottom about "[WS Message] blackjack.v3.game")

So my question is is there any way to get it using Python Selenium?
Thank.

These are the ones I want to get (all lines with "[WS Message] blackjack.v3.game"):
[image]

This is where they use console.log:
[image]

***Update: I tried the same with C# instead of Python and it worked just the way I wanted***

Comment: What did you mean "none of them work"? Please [edit] your question to show each version of code that you tried and explain what happens when you run them, including output or error messages.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I fixed it. All returned results do not include the lines I want in the first image above

Comment: If you still need help, [edit] your question to show the code that uses `driver.get_log('browser')` and the output you get when you run that code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just added